# Rails Invalid query parameters: Non UTF-8 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have encoded an URL with tracking parameters containing accents "Réseau Social"

```
https://www.example.com/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=R%E9seau+Social&utm_campaign=test
```

> An exception occurred: 'Invalid query parameters: Non UTF-8 value:
>   R�seau social' on
>   '/var/www/mysite-prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/request/utils.rb:26:in
>   `check_param_encoding''

The accent was encoded as `R%E9seau+Social`, isn't Rails supposed to process it correctly ?

Comment: You can give the `utf8-cleaner` gem a try.

Comment: I don't understand why it is invalid (é is a valid UTF8-character). In general when you have text field inputs in Rails forms, it's totally fine to write accents right ? I don't want to remove characters as the gem seems to do...

Comment: It's a complex topic. When you look into your response from a form, you will notice that rails always contains a utf char as a hidden field in your form, to ensure that the browser sends it response as a uft-8 encoded form. Within a query string its more complex. I don't know all components which influence the encoding and what your webserver "thinks" what encoding it has.

Comment: How have you encoded this character? What have you used to encode it?

Comment: Well you can see it in my code extract : `utm_medium=R%E9seau`. I have used an UTM link builder, not really sure what happened under the hood.

Comment: So, you encoded `é` in Latin1 (it was by no means “HTML encoded”,) then passed it to the server, that expects UTF-8.